# Black screen when loading iPad Storyboard.

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, ios-universal-app

So I am working on an app https://github.com/Kronusdark/PerlinNoiseKit and I had a (crappy) iPhone UI going, but I decided to make it run on my iPad. The problem is that when it loads the iPad storyboard, I get a black screen. I have checked my project summary and it is pointing to the correct storyboard file. The outlets all appear to be set correctly, and it will actually run code in my viewController on my iPad. I just get no UI. I have pushed my most recent changes to my repo if anyone wants to try to run it, any advice would be helpful.

Comment: I can't take a look at the code, as I'm not on a mac at the moment, but I just want to make sure, you changed the settings in your project to run on iPad, right?  Or at least made it "universal"?

Comment: yea, under summary right? its set to Universal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eureka! It turns out one of my sub-views were not working properly. After I removed the offending view my storyboard loaded no problem. I believe it was due to a rogue drawRect:.